# how to remove the word About on my AboutDialogInfo

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I develop an application with `wxpython` and I want to remove the word About when the `AboutDialogInfo` appears.

```
import wx
import wx.adv
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
     def __init__(self):
          About(self)
     def About(self):
        aboutInfo = wx.adv.AboutDialogInfo()
             aboutInfo.Name = ("Mome")
             aboutInfo.SetVersion("0.0.1")
             aboutInfo.SetDescription(
                 "Lorem Ipsum est un générateur de faux textes aléatoires\n"
                 "Lorem Ipsum est un générateur de faux textes aléatoires\n"
                 "Lorem Ipsum est un générateur de faux textes aléatoires\n"
                 )
        aboutInfo.SetCopyright("(C) 2019")
        aboutInfo.SetWebSite("http://www.google.com")
        aboutInfo.AddDeveloper("My Name")
        aboutInfo.SetLicence("This programm is .....")
        wx.adv.AboutBox(aboutInfo)
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't `AboutDialogInfo` expected to have the `About` built-in? From [it's method summary](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.AboutDialogInfo.html#method-summary-methods-summary), it seems to be a _very_ specialized form of a dialog.

Comment: Hello . indeed my application is not in English that's why I would like to remove it (About) to translate into my language.

Comment: Does the dialog change the language when you change OS locale? That is, I suspect that "About Mome" should change to something "A propos de Mome" if you set the French locale. In any case, WX has some built-in i18n support, and probably it's best to somehow make it work. (I'm no expert in that, though)